# Alternative to explode function for the following code

Tags: php, optimization, explode

```
$full_str = <img class="label" title="input contactusform email" id="label_contactusform_email" alt="this is alt tag">
```

I have this string expression and need to fetch title and alt tag value

```
$exploded_part = explode('="', $full_str);
$title_text = $exploded_part[2];

// it also included '" id' so need to explode again

$title_revised = explode('"', $title_text);
$actual_title = $title_revised[0];

$alt_text = $exploded_part[4];

// it also included '">' so need to explode again

$alt_revised = explode('"', $alt_text);

$actual_alt = $alt_revised[0];
```

I have read using explode takes so much resources and affects the performance and in this code have to use multiple times. Any ideas suggestions I can make this code better and use some other options except explode.

Edited: When I am using the below expression at that time it is not actually the part of DOM it's only a part of an array value and I have to put the fetched alt and title tags in the element to be part of DOM. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Well, you're not wrong, it's O(n), but still unless that array contains thousands upon thousands of elements, you should be fine.

Comment: can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression to extract the attributes and their values:

```
(\S+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?
```

https://regex101.com/r/rK2bC0/1

Comment: Regular expressions are actually worst than what OP has atm.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) like as

```
$full_str = '<img class="label" title="input contactusform email" id="label_contactusform_email" alt="this is alt tag">';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($full_str);
$root = $dom->documentElement;
$getDiv = $root->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($getDiv as $val) {
    $title = $val->getAttribute('title');
    $alt = $val->getAttribute('alt');
}

echo $alt;
echo $title;
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/441548)